# How to get/set the cell value of a JTable by its column name

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Is it possible to get or set the the cell value of a JTable by column name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Didn't find a built in method in JTable, but how about this:

```
private int getColumnByName(JTable table, String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); ++i)
        if (table.getColumnName(i).equals(name))
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Then you can use the following to set & get cell values :

```
table.setValueAt(value, rowIndex, getColumnByName(table, colName));

table.getValueAt(rowIndex, getColumnByName(table, colName));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get a TableColumn from JTable's getColumn method, using the name of the column as the identifier; and get its modelIndex....

but if your table has sorting; then you need to do translation.

I'd recommend implementing what you need in the tableModel for your table.