# update excel cell in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In a excel particular cell has input such as contact name as "Test-01" when the code is run contact name is displayed.Now i want to edit the same sheet and cell i.e contact name to "ABCD-200" and it should be displayed when code is run again.please can anyone tell me how to do it in selenium webdriver.

Comment: How you want to update `Excel` file with `Selenium`? Target spreadsheet displayed on webpage or what?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using JTable, refer to below code:

```
private int getColumnByName(JTable table, String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); ++i)
        if (table.getColumnName(i).equals(name))
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Then you can use the following to set & get cell values :

```
table.setValueAt(value, rowIndex, getColumnByName(table, colName));

table.getValueAt(rowIndex, getColumnByName(table, colName));
```

If you are using POI, refer to below code:

```
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xls");

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
Cell cell = row.getCell(3);
if (cell == null)
    cell = row.createCell(3);
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
cell.setCellValue("a test");

// Write the output to a file
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

You can modify above code as per your requirement to get particular row and column.

Reference Links :
http://www.coderanch.com/t/537168/java/java/Writing-existing-excel-xls-file

[How to get/set the cell value of a JTable by its column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034073/how-to-get-set-the-cell-value-of-a-jtable-by-its-column-name)