# Update excel file using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In my application, there are two buttons(export & import ). Using the export button I can download an excel file, in that downloaded excel file, there are lots of blanks fields.

I need to upload the same file using import button but if I upload the same file then I can get many mandatory fields validation message because of blank fields. Instead of uploading the same file I have another excel file, in which every blank field are filled.

In the exported file, there is a unique id which is generated in the run time and I have to set the same unique id into another excel file, in which every blank field are filled same as the exported file but unique id is different. otherwise, I will get a validation message.

I want to replace the epricer quote number 8766876 to  4181981 in new import file.

[image]

Comment: Selenium is used to drive browsers. It is not used to update Excel. You should probably do some googling on how to do this. There is plenty of info already existing on the web on how to open and edit Excel files with various libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly duplicate of following question :
[update excel cell in selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786955/update-excel-cell-in-selenium-webdriver)

Possible solution from link :

```
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xls");

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
Cell cell = row.getCell(3);
if (cell == null)
    cell = row.createCell(3);
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
cell.setCellValue("a test");

// Write the output to a file
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update Excel using Selenium, Selenium is a series of libraries that are used to drive a browser, they cannot interact with Excel documents.

If you want to interact with Excel documents you will need to use a library specifically designed to do that, some options are:

- [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org)
- [DocX4J](https://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j)
- [JExcelAPI](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/)